# How do I write VBS to change a value in a recordset if it is NULL?

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic

Here is my code:

```
        <table width=600 Border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=3>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor = Blue><center><font Color = WHITE size ="2"><B>NUMBER</B></font></center></td>
                <td bgcolor = Blue><center><font Color = WHITE size ="2"><B>NAME</B></font></center></td>
                <td bgcolor = Blue><center><font Color = WHITE size ="2"><B>FS Tax</B></font></center></td>
                <td bgcolor = Blue><center><font Color = WHITE size ="2"><B>Beer Tax</B></font></center></td>
            </tr>   
            <%
            'Open the recordset object executing the SQL statement and return records 
            Recordset.Open SQL,Connection

            'first of all determine whether there are any records 
            If Recordset.EOF Then 
            Response.Write("No records returned.") 
            Else 
            'if there are records then loop through the fields 
            Do While NOT Recordset.Eof  
            Response.write "<tr>"
            Response.write "<td>" & Recordset("Number") & "</td>"
            Response.write "<td>" & Recordset("Location_Name") & "</td>"
            If IsNull(FS_Tax) Then
                Response.write "<td>" & "None" & "</td>"
            End If
            Response.write "<td>" & Recordset("FS_Tax") & "%" & "</td>"
            Response.write "<td>" & Recordset("Beer_Tax") & "%" & "</td>" 
            Response.write "</tr>" 
            Recordset.MoveNext     
            Loop
            End If
            %>
        </table>
```

The table is ignoring the "If IsNull(FS_Tax)" statement. Any ideas why?

I want it to change that value in the table to "None" rather than just showing "%" for a NULL value.

Comment: Note that if your IsNull condition is true, then you will be generating an extra column: one that says "None", and one that just has a percent sign in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable **FS_Tax** is not declared. Perhaps you meant the database field? If so, try the following:

```
If IsNull(Recordset("FS_Tax")) Then
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Fabio mentioned, `FS_Tax` is not a variable. If it's a column in your table, you need to use `Recordset("FS_Tax")` to retrieve its value.

Also, you can account for NULL in your original SQL statement instead of having to handle it in VBScript:

```
select isnull(FS_Tax,'None')[FS_Tax] from ...
```

That would ensure `FS_Tax` is never null when you read it from your recordset.